# Using secondary key to sum dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict structured like [a][b]=(c) such as:

```
{'cat': {1:1, 2:3, 3:1, 4:1}, 'dog': {1:8, 2:2, 3:4}, 'egg': {5:1, 6:2}, 'frog': {2:1, 4:1, 5:1}, 'nuts': {3:1}, 'idea': {4:1}}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is search by the [b] key and sum the corresponding c belonging to that. So I'd get the following outputs:

1: 9, 2: 6, 3: 6
...and so on.

Does this require restructuring of the dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate on the dictionary values which are dicts and sum up the values for each key using a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Then you'll simply access the result dictionary to find out the summed value for each key with no need to search:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {'cat': {1:1, 2:3, 3:1, 4:1}, 'dog': {1:8, 2:2, 3:4}, 'egg': {5:1, 6:2}, 'frog': {2:1, 4:1, 5:1}, 'nuts': {3:1}, 'idea': {4:1}}

result = defaultdict(int)
for i in d.values():
    for j in i:
        result[j] += i[j]

print(result)
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 9, 2: 6, 3: 6, 4: 3, 5: 2, 6: 2})
```

---

```
>>> print(result[1])
9
```

Comment: You could also use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which already provides numeric values by default, starting at zero.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have such dictionary:

```
d = {'cat': {1:1, 2:3, 3:1, 4:1}, 'dog': {1:8, 2:2, 3:4}, 'egg': {5:1, 6:2}, 'frog': {2:1, 4:1, 5:1}, 'nuts': {3:1}, 'idea': {4:1}}}
```

Now we have to write a function which will take a parameter (an integer) and sum all values for this integer across all inner dictionaries.

```
def calc(b):
    result = 0
    for val in d.values():
        if b in val:
            result += val[b]
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the total then you can `sum` up all the values using:

```
>>> b = 2
>>> sum(a.get(b, 0) for a in d.values())
6
```

If you want all the `b`s then you use `collections.Counter()` which behaves like a `dict` to do all the heavy lifting:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> sum((Counter(a) for a in d.values()), Counter())
Counter({1: 9, 2: 6, 3: 6, 4: 3, 5: 2, 6: 2})
```

But if you are really fussy and want a `dict`:

```
>>> dict(sum((Counter(a) for a in d.values()), Counter()))
{1: 9, 2: 6, 3: 6, 4: 3, 5: 2, 6: 2}
```

Comment: The answer should be a dictionary.